# Reformat data leaving numeric digits without separators

Tags: cobol

I have a field containing article-numbers (PIC X(25)).

Example article number: 12345-6789.

The problem is the "-", I need to delete the "-" and put together the 5 and 6, result example: 123456789

Using Micro Focus Net Express 5.1 running on a UNIX server. The position of the dash is not fixed.

Comment: Can you tell us which COBOL compiler and OS? Is the data in a fixed format (always five numbers, dash, four numbers)? If not, can you provide some more examples, please?

Comment: We need to know answer for Bill's questions. If the number of digits before/after the "-" is always the same, there is a fairly simple answer. If either before/after length changes, if the position of the "-" changes, the answer needs to be more complex. If the platform/OS/compiler is specific, it might limit or expand possibilities.

Comment: I am using Micro Focus Net Express 5.1 running on a UNIX -server. The position of the dash is random. The article numbers are stored in an ISAM-file and are read from there.

Comment: You reallise that 123-456 and 1-23456 will give the same result? What are you going to do with the result? We can assume one "-" only per article-number and always one "-"?

Comment: The file is read by another system that is sensible to dash. I need to get rid of the dash

Answer (score 1):

Take this code for a spin.

Update: Good catch, Bill. I just wanted to give options, depending what the needs and demands truly were.

```
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   SPECIAL-NAMES.
  *    ClassIncludeList and ClassExcludeList can now be referenced much like NUMERIC
       CLASS ClassIncludeList IS '0123456789'
       CLASS ClassExcludeList IS '-'
       .

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01  InputStringText              PIC X(1000).
   01  InputStringLength            PIC 9(04) COMP.
   01  OutputStringText             PIC X(1000).
   01  OutputStringLength           PIC 9(04) COMP.
   01  ByteSubscript                PIC 9(04) COMP.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

       MOVE article-numbers TO InputStringText.
       MOVE FUNCTION LENGTH(article-numbers) TO InputStringLength.

       PERFORM IncludeCharacters.
  *    Use OutputStringText(OutputStringLength)

       PERFORM ExcludeCharacters.
  *    Use OutputStringText(OutputStringLength)

   IncludeCharacters.
       MOVE SPACES TO OutputStringText
       MOVE ZERO TO OutputStringLength
       PERFORM
         VARYING ByteSubscript FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL ByteSubscript > InputStringLength
               IF (InputStringText(ByteSubscript:1) IS ClassIncludeList)
                   ADD 1 TO OutputStringLength
                   MOVE InputStringText(ByteSubscript:1)
                     TO OutputStringText(OutputStringLength:1)
               END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       .

   ExcludeCharacters.
       MOVE SPACES TO OutputStringText
       MOVE ZERO TO OutputStringLength
       PERFORM
         VARYING ByteSubscript FROM 1 BY 1
           UNTIL ByteSubscript > InputStringLength
               IF (InputStringText(ByteSubscript:1) IS ClassExcludeList)
                   CONTINUE
               ELSE
                   ADD 1 TO OutputStringLength
                   MOVE InputStringText(ByteSubscript:1)
                     TO OutputStringText(OutputStringLength:1)
               END-IF
       END-PERFORM
       .
```

Comment: Not sure why you have the Include and Exclude. Interesting to use the CLASS-test with reference-modification. I've not seen that before, so that'll get you a vote. A more readable version of James's. Bear in mind that you've defined all your subscripts and counts with only two digits, yet you input and output show 1000 bytes. 9(4) would be clearer, even if it happens to work on some implementations or with some compile options.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work on any modern COBOL:

```
01  INPUT-STRING    PIC X(25).
01  OUTPUT-STRING   PIC X(25).
01  IX              PIC S9(8) COMP SYNC.
01  OX              PIC S9(8) COMP SYNC.
```

...

```
MOVE +1 TO OX.
MOVE ALL ' ' TO OUTPUT-STRING.
PERFORM VARYING IX FROM 1 BY 1
          UNTIL IX > 25
     IF NOT INPUT-STRING(IX:1) = '-'
     THEN
         MOVE INPUT-STRING(IX:1) TO OUTPUT-STRING(OX:1)
         ADD +1 TO OX
     END-IF
END-PERFORM.
```

Comment: @Bill Wooger -- will fix it. Have not  touched a COBOL compiler for five years :-)

Comment: Thanks, tidying away. Guess we're not going to here from OP again, anyway

Answer (score 0):

There's always `UNSTRING` and `STRING` if your Cobol supports them, and if there is a limit to how many 'parts' there are going to be in the text.

```
01  ARTICLE-NUMBER         PIC X(25).
01  PARTS.
    05 PART1               PIC X(25).
    05 PART2               PIC X(25).
    05 PART3               PIC X(25).
    05 PART4               PIC X(25).
01  RESULT                 PIC X(25).
```

........

```
INITIALIZE PARTS, RESULT.
UNSTRING ARTICLE-NUMBER
   DELIMITED BY '-'
   INTO PART1, PART2, PART3, PART4
   ON OVERFLOW
      DISPLAY "Too many parts!!!"
END-UNSTRING.
STRING PART1, PART2, PART3, PART4
       DELIMITED BY SPACE INTO RESULT.
```

Hope this helps.